# Что-то жрет CPU

Tags: linux

Помогите понять что жрет cpu, почему такие скачки? как бороться?
Что проверить?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D6BX.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPcjy.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FSi7.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7uuG.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOAh2.jpg

Comment: Картинки надо в сам вопрос загружать.

Comment: Коронавирус, наверное. Проверьте иммунитет)

Comment: Вы же уже привели картинку, где показывается, что и сколько жрет, о чем вопрос?

Comment: @user7860670, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Ну отключите веб сервер и mysql